# Acessar dados de um objeto js

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho o seguinte objeto JS exibido pelo console.log
[image: console.log]

Só consigo acessar a propriedade status do objeto em si, mas preciso acessar a propriedade status que está dentro do objeto value e possui o valor 400, mas todos os tipos de assessores de propriedade que tento dão undefined quando tento ir além do primeiro status (de valor 0) apresentado. Alguém pode me ajudar? Gostaria de saber também qual o nome que se dá para essas propriedades "internas" do objeto?

Comment: Como você tentou? Pelo log, deve ser objeto.value.status. Talvez o problema não seja a forma de acesso, e sim o momento em que você tenta acessar esses dados (pode ser quecestja tentando acessar antes dos dados estarem disponíveis, caso venham por Ajax)

Comment: Para acessar é o que o bfavarreto falou, já com relação ao nome sua pergunta é a resposta, tanto que o método para retornar as nome das propriedades interna é `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` sao propriedades não?

Comment: Realmente se trata de uma requisição ajax feita por uma função Restangular.all, talvez seja a questão de os dados não estarem disponíveis a tempo. Estou tentando com `object.value.status` mas recebo undefined ou Tried to load AngularJS more than once

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o trecho de código que faz a requisição, e o trecho que tenta tratar a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o **bfavaretto** disse veja o momento que está acessando os dados, pois pode ainda não estar disponível, mas a sintaxe é esta como no exemplo. Você tem um objeto **dados**, que para acessar qualquer uma das suas propriedades basta colocar o **.** antes da propriedade. No seu caso aí pela imagem não tem nenhum **array** senão você teria que acessar o índice da propriedade para pegar seu valor:

```js
var dados = {
  pure: true,
  status: 2,
  value: {
    data: "",
    status: 400,
    headers: "bla-bla-bla"
  }
}

console.log(dados.status +" - "+ dados.value.status );
```

Comment: Repara na saída do console que a pergunta mostra. Parece que o valor de `status` era `0` no momento do log, e `2` no momento em que ele expandiu o objeto. Tá com muita cara de o problema ser outro: tentar acessar dado de operação assíncrona antes de ele estar disponível.

Comment: Sim, verdade.  Provavelmente o problema era este mesmo.

Comment: Pessoal, optamos por alterar o backend que o verdadeiro causador do problema que está ocorrendo ao lançar uma exceção indevida, a tentativa no JS era mais uma tentativa de resolver na gambiarra do que de resolver de fato o problema.